# How to design a red colour semi transparent drawer item header

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[I am trying to make a semi transparent drawer header like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1tVM.jpg)

[This is my Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ustao.png)

This is my header.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:background="#AA0010"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
android:layout_height="76dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile"
app:border_color="#FF000000"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


    android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Akash Bangad"

    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />
```

And, This is my NavigationView defined inside

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/red"
    />
```

Someone please guide, where I am making a mistake and how to make this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set opacy, you can add this in the xml:

```
 android:alpha="'you can try the opacy here'"
```

For example :

```
android:alpha="255"
```

Comment: There is no change in transparency, in which xml file should I add this. Can you please be more specific

Comment: Try to add it to your NavigationView.xml

Comment: Its opacity is increased. Still I'm not getting the transparency of the layout, please take a look at this. I want a header layout like this i.stack.imgur.com/u1tVM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
android:alpha
```

Or you can use background color with two digit before color code like:

```
android:background="#55AA0010"
```

Above hex code use for red transparent. You can use 00 to 99 before color code.

Comment: can we use this to set opacity of images aswell?

Comment: Its opacity is increased. Still I'm not getting the transparency of the layout, please take a look at this. I want a header layout like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/u1tVM.jpg

Comment: @ShanPLT use background color like above example and try 00 to 99 combination.